# PayPal GetUserLimits Explanation

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

PayPal AdaptivePayments API has method GetUserLimits can anyone explain its purpose?

We have already tried to make the call but it throws "Internal Error (520002)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetUserLimits API is used to get the various deposit/withdrawal limits of a specified account.  This API requires special permission as it's use is not granted to everyone.